# Adding activate event listener to service worker

Tags: javascript, html, css, service-worker

I have a service worker I am trying to setup for my website. It uses basic html, and css. I need it to cache the files for offline mode. I currently am stuck at adding the activate event listener, and setting up my fetch function. How do I intergrate that, and am I missing anything greater? Thanks.

LINK - https://jsfiddle.net/scgdhusk/2/

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... adding the activate event listener is very simple:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  // do whatever you want
});
```

However, since your question is so simple I take it that you haven't really read through all the recommended documentation but just started to hack something together. I really advice you to read Google's introduction to Service Workers. There are many, many footguns that you can avoid if you read the material.

:)

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/